# SPSS IBM Modeler: String splittting

Tags: string, split, numeric, spss-modeler

I have a column containing string values of the different year values called "lease_commence_date". I am trying to categorize the values into 3 categories namely "Between 1960 and 2000" , "Between 2000 and 2010" , "After 2010"
The expression i used here is:

```
IF (NUM(lease_commence_date) > 1960) AND (NUM(lease_commence_date) < 2000) THEN "Between 1960 and 2000"
ELSEIF (NUM(lease_commence_date) > 2000) AND (NUM(lease_commence_date) < 2010) THEN "Between 2000 and 2010"
ELSE "After 2010"
ENDIF
```

In this expressison, i have tried to convert the string values into numerical first so that the numerical operators could be applied. However, I keep getting the error 'Missing operator before 'AND' '. I can't seem to figure out where the issue is. Please advise. Thank you.